# What if an interrupt is raised after a cli instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86

The following code results in a segmentation fault:

```
mov $1, %eax
mov $2, %ebx
cli
int $0x80
```

Clearly **cli** disables interrupts, but just out of curiosity I'd like to know what really happens with the cpu underneath the hood.

Also, are double/triple faults related to this?

Comment: _CLI_ is a privileged instruction and when executed in Linux userland code it will segfault. I assume from this code you are using Linux? (ie `int $0x80`)

Comment: Cli doesn't disable software interrupts such as int 0x80, but only external interrupts.

Comment: A double fault can occur when one of the data structures needed to handle a fault is not set up correctly. IDT, GDT, stack, or page tables, typically. Not anything that can be modified in user mode.

Comment: Specifically, executing [`cli` raises a `#GP(0)` exception "*If the CPL is greater (has less privilege) than the IOPL of the current program or procedure.*"](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CLI.html).  This #GP is what results in the segfault.

Comment: So under Linux, you could make an [`iopl(3)` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/iopl.2.html) and then you could disable interrupts from user-space.  (And probably crash your system if you don't re-enable them right away, or at least screw up that CPU on a multi-core system).  Basically don't do this unless you're ready to press the reset button, i.e. shut down X11, saved your files and run `sync`.  Also remount filesystems read-only.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I saw that you posted a more concise answer for the other question, since I don't have enough reputation I'll comment here. You said "**Software-generated interrupts like int $0x80 are still taken, but making system calls with interrupts disabled is probably an even worse idea.**" Does that mean the result is undefined?

Comment: @PeterCordes Also, what exactly are external interrupts?

Comment: external as in timer interrupt or NIC packet-received interrupt.

Comment: "worse idea" as in "I have no idea what will happen".  Maybe the system call will run fine, maybe it will return to user-space with interrupts enabled.  It might not be as unsafe as I was thinking, though, because user-space EFLAGS / RFLAGS is saved/restored.  So I don't think there's any chance it will context-switch to another process with interrupts still disabled or something.  (`IF` is a bit in EFLAGS.)

Comment: @Trey: To be more accurate, CLI causes the external interrupts to be postponed (their delivery to the CPU is disabled, so they wait until delivery is enabled again) - they don't just disappear. CLI is typically only used when you're changing something an IRQ handler relies on (to guard against "IRQ occurs at exactly the wrong time and something it relies on isn't sane at that specific moment").